Multi-Condition Handling with errorlevel
Using a script for Python dependencies, I want to pause execution if the errorlevel returns 1, and exit if execution of the commands is successful and errorlevel returns 0.
py devscripts/install_deps.py --include py2exe
py devscripts/make_lazy_extractors.py
py -m bundle.py2exe
if %errorlevel% equ "1" (pause) else (exit /b)

Currently the script closes the terminal window regardless of the errorlevel return value, what do I need to do to meet my requirements?

The comparisons used are neither equivalent nor equitable in their elements: not using double quotes around the first element makes cmd treat it as an integer, while the quoted "1" is treated as a string.
:: Note: Example considers the error level value as 1. // %errorlevel% equ 1

 if [ " ]%errorlevel%[ " ] == [ " ] 1 [ " ] (pause) else (exit /b) ✅
 
 if [ " ]%errorlevel%[ " ] == [ " ] 1 [ " ] (pause) else (exit /b) ❌
 if [ " ]%errorlevel%[ " ] == [ " ] 1 [ " ] (pause) else (exit /b) ❌

 if [ " ]%errorlevel%[ " ] equ [ " ] 1 [ " ] (pause) else (exit /b) ❌
 if [ " ]%errorlevel%[ " ] equ [ " ] 1 [ " ] (pause) else (exit /b) ❌

 if [ " ]%errorlevel%[ " ] equ [ " ] 1 [ " ] (pause) else (exit /b) ✅
 if [   ]%errorlevel%[   ] equ [   ] 1 [   ] (pause) else (exit /b) ✅
 if      %errorlevel%      equ       1       (pause) else (exit /b) ✅

       Integer      equ   Integer   true 
 if %errorlevel%    equ   integer  (pause) else (exit /b)

      "Strings"     equ  "Strings"  true 
 if "%errorlevel%"  equ     "1"    (pause) else (exit /b)

      "Strings"     equ  "Strings"  true 
 if "%errorlevel%"  ==      "1"    (pause) else (exit /b)



To make the comparisons comparable and equitable:

if       1        equ   1  (true) else (false)
if      "1"       ==   "1" (true) else (false)
if  %errorlevel%  equ   1  (true) else (false)
if "%errorlevel%" equ  "1" (true) else (false)
if "%errorlevel%" ==   "1" (true) else (false)



Some further reading:

If /?

An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com


